# Use Laravel Socialite user returns missing authorization_code

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite, superoffice-api

I'm using Laravel Socialite to login with SuperOffice API. Have only just added the provider as a [pr](https://github.com/SocialiteProviders/Providers/pull/586) but testing it already. I'm using the provider `superoffice` locally and inside a package `superoffice-api` I'm creating. Have added both packages to composer.json in the Laravel app:

```json
"repositories": [
     {
         "type": "path",
         "url": "./packages/superoffice-api"
     },
     {
        "type": "path",
        "url": "./packages/superoffice"
     }
]
```

Also added the `superoffice` Socialite provider in the `superoffice-api` composer.json in the same way.

The login process is working but the problem starts when trying to use the user for other API calls. What I mean with this is on the callback I can do the following:

```php
public function superofficeCallback(Request $request): RedirectResponse
{
     $user = Socialite::driver('superoffice')->stateless()->user();

     return redirect()->route('dashboard.index')->with([
         'message' => 'Loggedin with SuperOffice as '.$user->name,
         'success' => true,
      ]);
}
```

This shows the `$user->name` as expected. Now when trying to call `Socialite::driver('superoffice')->stateless()->user()` in the `superoffice-api` package I get the following error message:

> GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client error: `POST https://sod.superoffice.com/login/common/oauth/tokens` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response:
> { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "missing authorization_code"}

It doesn't matter if called in a method or in the `__construct()` of a class.

So my question is how can I use a Socialite provider `superoffice` user in a package `superoffice-api`? This is needed to get the `access_token`. Can imagine that because Socialite is called in a package some sort of reference is missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the `access_token` and `refresh_token` need to be stored in some other way in the callback function. When stored for example in the database you're able to use the tokens anywhere.